# Get data from encrypted sqlite database using sqlite3.exe

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a password protected database which I have created using `System.Data.Sqlite.dll` in *.net* windows application.

Now I want to write a script to fetch data from this database using `sqlite3.exe.` How to provide password using `sqlite3.exe` and get the data from this database? If I directly use the select command, it throws error: `"Error: file is encrypted or is not a database"`

Answer (score 0):

After opening the database via sqlite.exe, use PRAGMA KEY before issuing any additional SELECT/etc. statements:

```
PRAGMA KEY="MyPassword";
```

**EDIT**:
It looks like System.Data.Sqlite.dll does not use the semi-standard encryption code found in many SQLite binaries. Instead, it uses the Windows Crypto APIs. **The above answer will not work.**

Comment: Hi NuSkooler, I have tried your suggestion but it didn't work. It gave the same error message saying file is encrypted or is not a database.

Comment: Updated my answer. I'll update it more if I get some time. It looks like what you need is a sqlite.exe compiled against the Windows Crypto APIs.